# EF is trying to insert new child record before new parent record during SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using database first and have a parent entity that has a collection of child entities. When I am adding both at the same time I am getting a FK constraint in the DB and when I log EF's commands I see that it is sending the sql command to insert the child record first in the UOW and of course it blows up.

The code is first adding the Ticket using `dbSet.Add` and then it adds the StockTicket to `Ticket.StockTickets`. It then calls `SaveChanges()`

I have also tried to add both Ticket and StockTicket to their respective dbSets and then manually add the StockTicket to `Ticket.StockTickets` and the Ticket to `StockTicket.Ticket`, but that doesn't work either

Nothing works and I haven't run into this before; I have worked with EF quite a bit.

```
public partial class Ticket 
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        this.StockTickets = new HashSet<StockTicket>();         
    }

    public long TicketID { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<StockTicket> StockTickets { get; set; }
}

public partial class StockTicket
{
    public long StockTicketID { get; set; }
    ...

    public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
}

// base repository methods
protected void Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity", "The entity argument is null.");
    }

    var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
    entry.Property("isActive").CurrentValue = true;
    _dbSet.Add(entity);
}

public void Save()
{
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Calling code in my service:

```
ticket.ticketID = GetNextSequence();
_repository.Insert(ticket);
ticket.StockTickets.Add(stockTicket);
_repository.Save();
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you're actually populating your models and saving changes?

Comment: When posting additional code please modify the question so the code is readable rather than posting it in the comments. That code you provided is a base-class method that still doesn't show the what's actually executing when you're adding `Ticket` and `StockTicket` though.